# Sort a magento collection by altered attribute

Tags: magento2

I need to sort a collection by an attribute, taking into account only the numbers and decimal places of this attribute, ignoring the letters. I don't think there is anyway to use addAttributeToSort here. On version Magento 2.3.

The collection is of catalog_product_entity. The attribute I need to sort by is in catalog_product_entity_text. The collection is filtered by another attribute already, no further filtering needed, just sort.

The attribute and value are in catalog_product_entity_text; let's call the attribute test_group and it can have values similar to this: CA350, AB100, B225, BB100.5 etc..

How can I sort the collection so I end up with the collection in the order of AB100, BB100.5, B225, CA350?

I've tried `$collection->getItems()`, sort these items, delete items in collection, push these sorted items to collection. This results in very slow performance, so I would like to utilize mysql to handle the sorting, like `addAttributeToSort` does. I also do not want to overwrite the existing attribute in the collection.

I'm still learning mysql and haven't had any success with my attempts, but I'm thinking something like

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array(
        'catalog_product_entity_text'=>"catalog_product_entity_text"),
        '`main_table`.`test_group_no_char`=`catalog_product_entity_text`.`value`')
```

but with the test_group_no_char not containing letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
$giftColletion = $this->_giftFactory->getCollection();
$giftColletion->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 1);
$giftColletion->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

`setOrder` is use for sorting

Comment: Thanks for looking, but I have to sort the attribute using only the numbers (ignoring the letters). The attribute will contain a combination of both such as: AB100. It needs to sort just using the 100 part of the attribute. Using setOrder doesn't work for this.

Comment: I don't know any solution for what you are looking for. Even I don't think it's possible